# Automatically Delete Corresponding Bracket in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, brackets, auto-completion

Let me start off by saying that I'm *not* looking for how to disable bracket completion. In fact, when I tried searching for what I'm about to ask, that kind of information was the only thing that kept coming up...

What I'm looking for is something akin to how a typical programming compiler will handle bracket auto-completion. For example, I program in Python with Spyder a lot, and when I accidentally open any sort of ([{ bracket, although initially the bracket is auto-completed on the other side with a )]}, if I were to delete that bracket, it also automatically removes the corresponding bracket. In TeXstudio, however, hitting backspace on the accidental bracket leaves the "closing" bracket in the file.

Although it's not a difficult task per se to delete the other bracket manually when this happens, 50 pages of latex in and I'm starting to think that someone smarter than me must have already thought of a way to solve this. Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I would love to see a good answer to this. It is really easy to get used to this convenience feature in IDEs like RStudio.

Comment: @tmastny See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of time of writing, I do not think there is an option to delete corresponding brackets automatically (which is a shame :o). 
There is a way to do this via a macro/user script in TeXstudio, but is slightly more involved, so I'll lay it out in a step-by-step manner.

## User script for "Automatically deleting corresponding brackets"

> **Notes on use:** The following script deletes both brackets in `()`, `{}` or `[]` automatically when (i) the cursor is *in between* the open and close brackets and (ii) the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is pressed. Such situations in TeXstudio arise most frequently when "Auto Complete Parenthesis" option is turned on. (See Gif demonstration below.)

1. From the main toolbar, go to `Macros -> Edit Macros`. Click `Add +` on the bottom left corner of the pop-up window to add a new user script. Paste the following in the large box that says `LaTeX content` on the right side of the pop-up window:

   ```
   %SCRIPT
   previousChar = function() {return String.fromCharCode(cursor.previousChar())};
   nextChar = function() {return String.fromCharCode(cursor.nextChar())};
   var Obrackets = ['(','[','{'];
   var Cbrackets = [')',']','}'];
   var Omatch = Obrackets.indexOf(previousChar());
   var Cmatch = Cbrackets.indexOf(nextChar());
   if(Omatch>=0 && Cmatch==Omatch){
       cursor.deleteChar();
   }
   if(cursor.hasSelection()){
       cursor.removeSelectedText();
   } else {
       cursor.deletePreviousChar();
   }
   ```

   Give it a name if you like (for ease of finding it in Step 2). Close out of the macros window.

[image: pic1]

2. From the main toolbar, go to `Options -> Configure TeXstudio`, and navigate to:

   ```
   Shortcuts -> Menus -> Macros
   ```

   and find the macro that you created in the first step. Change the `Current shortcut` for this macro to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

[image: pic2]

You might get a warning about replacing the functionality of the current <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, but you can just ignore that (because the script takes the normal functionality of <kbd>Backspace</kbd> into account).

**[Extra]** At any point in time, if you would like to restore the original functionality, an easy way is by deleting the macro (or restoring it to its default shortcut) and then:

```
    Shortcuts -> Editor -> Basic Key Mapping -> Delete left character
```

and change it back to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

3. Test it out! (Note that in the .gif, I have "Auto Complete Parenthesis" from `Adv. Editor` options turned on).

[image: gif]

Comment: Wow! A+ answer, thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @AlkaKadri Cheers :) It's a problem I wanted to solve for a long time myself as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the braces (or curly brackets) you want to delete simultaneously are delimiting the scope of a command, you can put the cursor on the word associated with the command and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

For example,

```
\textbf{text}
```

will output

> text

I'm not aware if there is a way to do the same for other types of bracket.

[Source](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION39)

Comment: `Alt+Del` deletes the text *within* the brackets, not the brackets themselves. Also, even if did delete the brackets, I don't think that it's not the exact problem that the OP was trying to solve.

Comment: If you look closely at section 2.15 of the source I provided, it says that: "the command is deleted including opening and closing braces", but it won't delete the text within the backets.

Comment: Fair enough, but this still does not answer the question imo. The OP is asking about deleting the closing brace automatically, in the scenario when OP has deleted the opening brace. (like the python example)

Comment: The way I understand the question, is that the OP wish there were a way to delete the closing bracket as he's deleting the opening one automatically (or simultaneously).
However, I agree that it doesn't answer the case where the brackets aren't linked to a command which is probably what the OP was referring to.

Comment: Even if the brackets *were* linked to a command, to use that `Alt+Del` shortcut to delete the brackets (and the command!) would require me to use the arrow keys to shift the cursor left, *then* enter the keyboard shortcut. At that point it seems to make more sense and typing efficiency to just press Backspace and Del to delete both brackets around the cursor..

Comment: I see your point. Hopefully, someone will have a better answer.

Comment: Although it does not answer the original question, it is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Now do you know how to delete the surrounding command while the cursor is still at "text"?